# PHP function & classes

Tags: php, class, function

maybe this is easy for most.
But sometimes in a piece of code i see something like this:

```
public function myFunction(Class_Name $var){
  //some nice code here
}
```

My question is, those paramaters what do they do and why do i want to use it? :)

Answer (score 9):

The `Class_Name` portion is a [type hint](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php). The `$var` parameter must be an instance of that class (whether a `new Class_Name()` or an instance of any class that derives from it). You use it if you expect `$var` to be a certain kind of object, and not just any arbitrary PHP value. Type hints only exist natively for class/interface types and arrays, though.

Comment: Type hints exist for arrays, too.

Answer (score 3):

This means that the variable, passed to myFunction **must be** instance of Class_Name. In this way you can avoid checking the type of the variable in the body of myFunction, or calling a method of $var whitout being sure that that method exists.

Answer (score 2):

A parameter is used for whatever you (or someone else) use it within the function/method.

```
public function myFunction(Class_Name $var){
  //some nice code here
  echo $var->someProperty;
}
```

If you are asking, whats `Class_Name` about: That's a type-hint. It means, that php will emit an error everytime you try to set anything else than an object of class `Class_Name` (or of an child class) as agument.

Answer (score 1):

That's called [typehinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) and it assures that the $var variable is an instance of either Class_Name, or a class that extends Class_Name. It's just an assertion, really.

Answer (score 0):

for a function arguments have to be defined if you want to return some result from the function .... class_name is like (int,float ...etc ) which is not necessarily be defined and $var can be any name you want your variable